# "command not found: vim"

Tags: vim, macvim

Today I wanted to "re-do" my vim installation, so I deleted some folders and files from the  /Users/myname/ path (only vim connected), I then deleted MacVim, because I wanted to install it freshly (using janus etc). However, now after trying to re install it my terminal gives me the command not found: vim error. I suspect a symlink/path error but I have no idea how to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you install the janus package?

- In your terminal, type `$ which vim`. What does it say?
- Do you still have `/usr/bin/vim`? Can you execute it?

  It's the default Vim, as installed with Mac OS X. You are not supposed to touch it in any way, for any reason. The only reason why it wouldn't be there would be because you have removed it or replaced it with a symlink to something that isn't there anymore.
- Do you still have `/usr/share/vim`?

  These are the support files of the default Vim above. Again, you shouldn't touch this folder.
- Do you still have `~/.vim`?

  This is where you are supposed to put your own support files. Did you delete it? Why?
- Do you still have `~/.vimrc`?

  This is your own `.vimrc`. Did you delete it? Why?

If you removed the default vim or you replaced it with a symlink and the symlink's target is gone there is no way to put it back except by reinstalling the whole system.

At this point, no Vim on your system, you must reinstall it. There are many ways to do it but you'll have to ask yourself a few questions:

1. Do I want a GUI only?
2. Do I want a CLI only?
3. Do I want both a CLI and a GUI?

The method depends on your answer:

- **GUI only**

  Install MacVim [from here](http://code.google.com/p/macvim/) or via [Homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew).
- **CLI only**

  1. Install [MacPorts.](http://www.macports.org/)
  2. Install Vim with this command:

     ```
     $ sudo port install vim +huge
     ```

  You can also install Vim [from source.](http://www.vim.org/download.php)
- **GUI + CLI**

  It's the same as the "GUI only" path. When the install is done, make sure you have the `mvim` script in your `$PATH` and add this line to your `~/.profile`:

  ```
  alias vim="mvim -v"
  ```

Comment: which vim: vim not found

/usr/bin/vim exists. -> "The operation can’t be completed because the original item for “vim” can’t be found."

/usr/share/vim exists. - didn't touch this. 

I still have ~/.vim and ~/.vimrc

I want CLI only and I'll look into it, thanks a lot.

Comment: OK, `/usr/bin/vim` is a symlink. It looks like you replaced the original vim by a symlink to whatever other Vim you had on your machine which was, obviously, a bad idea. Actually, even for "CLI only" I'd recommend to install MacVim as it is more powerful and faster than any Vim I've managed to build by hand.

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought. No idea how I ended up deleting the actual vim :/ Anyway, I installed it for CLI only (although I have MacVim setup as well) and it is now working again. So thanks! :)